# Proving that $A \mapsto A^T$ is an isomorphism for the vector space $M_{nn}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the map $A \mapsto A^T$ is an isomorphism for the vector space $M_{nn}$ of all $n \times n $ matrices to itself.

I know that I have to prove that this mapping is a linear transformation and that it is one-to-one and onto, but the abstractness throws me off. Can someone help explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map is linear since $(cA+B)^T=cA^T+B^T$ for any matrices $A,B$ and any scalar $c$, and is invertible because $(A^T)^T=A$. There's no need to show that it's injective and surjective because we've already found the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Establish the following facts would suffice:

1. If a linear map has $0$ nullity, then it is injective.
2. $A^\intercal = 0 \iff A = 0$
3. For every matrix, there exists another matrix whose transposition is that matrix.